# When I use Picasso to load image into ImageView, then setImageBitmap becomes has no effect

Tags: java, android, imageview, picasso

I have used Picasso lib to load images from server and it works fine for me but when I want to select another image from Gallery to load it into the same image view nothing happens.

Here is my code

```
Picasso.with(EditProfileActivity.this)
            .load(User.getInstance().getProfilePicPath())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.defaultpp)
            .error(R.drawable.defaultpp)
            .into(imageView);
```

By the way when I comment the above line, I can select an image and show it into the image view, so can anyone give the reason of what happened ?

Comment: you can use picaso for displaying local images as well

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load images from gallery, you can pass file URI into Picasso

```
 Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(fileUri).into(imageView);
```

---

You also have to make sure that you have enough permissions to fetch the given image.

Comment: I tried this line               
Picasso.with(EditProfileActivity.this).load(data.getData()).into(imageView); but nothing happened

Comment: what data.getData() returns?

Comment: You can also try  Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(new File(fileUri)).into(imageView); @KhalidAli

Comment: It return uri and it works fine except when using Picasso.
And it didn't work.

Comment: do you have enough permissions declared in manifest? can please paste an example of uri which data.getData() returns @KhalidAli

Comment: Something like this content://media/external/images/media/30027

Comment: May be you are missing the read external storage permission, if you are testing on a device grater than marshmallow, you have to request it at runtime

Comment: It works only when I use imageView.setImageBitmap() method instead of using Picasso. But after I use Picasso, it doesn't work even setImageBitmap. @Darish

Comment: @KhalidAli can you please add required permissions into your project?

Comment: I have already added these permissions WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the picasso lib, and has been answered by the creator itself, though solved in the latest version (but is still in alpha), a work around for picasso with Uri is this:

```
   Picasso.with(this).load("file://" + User.getInstance().getProfilePicPath()).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .config(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).into(imageview);
```

Make sure you dont forget the `file://` prefix

Ref: the issue tracker for Picasso [here](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/920)

Comment: When I pick an image from Gallery, how can I get the suffix of "file://" in onActivtyResult method ?

Comment: you wont get, you will get a uri. but when you set the uri to picasso add a prefix `file://`

Comment: I tried this line Picasso.with(this).load("file://" + data.getData()).placeholder(R.drawable.defaultpp)
                        .config(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).into(imageView);  but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

Because of when you select image your activity is sended back and imageviews route is lost. So yo have to define it again when it returns to your activity. add onResume or add onRestoreInstanceState then define imageview again ex: imageview findview... etc. It is the problem.

Comment: by the way i give positive your question because this is a good question. I have a smilar problem couple months ago and it take my lots of time. So i think your problem you have to define your image view again when activity come back. This is it.